# Prim's and Kruskal Algorithms in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I have to implement Prim's and Kruskal's algorithms in Java in order to find minimum spanning tree in a given undirected weighted graph. How can I do that ?  Implementation  must at least achieve O(2) for Prim’s Algorithm and O(3) for Kruskal’s Algorithm (n is the number of nodes).

```
public class Graph {
/*The following square matrix represents a weighted undirected graph.
    the value in (i,j) position indicates the cost between i and j node.
    Zeros indicate no connection*/

    static int[][] matrix = { { 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4 }, // 0
        { 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0 }, // 1
        { 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0 }, // 2
        { 2, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, // 3
        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8 }, // 4
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0 }, // 5
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0 }, // 6
        { 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, // 7
        { 4, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0 } // 8  
    };
    /*  static int[][] matrix = { { 0, 2, 3, 0, 0 }, // 0
                { 2, 0, 15, 2, 0 }, // 1
                { 3, 15, 0, 0, 13}, // 2
                { 0, 2, 0, 0, 9}, // 3
                { 0, 0, 13, 9, 0}, // 4 }; */

static int Node = matrix.length;
static int[][] Edge = new int[Node][Node];
static int NotConnected = 999999;

public static void MakeGraph() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Node; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Node; j++) {
            Edge[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
            if (Edge[i][j] == 0)// If Node i and Node j are not connected
                Edge[i][j] = NotConnected;
        }
    }
    // Print the graph representation matrix.
    for (int i = 0; i < Node; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Node; j++)
            if (Edge[i][j] != NotConnected)
                System.out.print(" " + Edge[i][j] + " ");
            else // when there is no connection
                System.out.print(" * ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void Prim(){
    System.out.println("OUPUT OF PRIM'S ALGORITHM:");
    // Write the code for Prim algorithm to find the minimum cost spanning tree here
    // and print the result in console with the following format:
    /*==========================OUTPUT FORMAT===========================
            Minimun Cost of Spanning Tree = "....... "       

            Edges of the minimum cost spanning tree:
            ".........................................................."
            (for example:
            Edges of the minimum cost spanning tree:
            "0 -- 1
             7 -- 2
             0 -- 3
             3 -- 4
             2 -- 5
             5 -- 6
             1 -- 7
             0 -- 8)"
    ================================================================== */

}

public static void Kruskal(){
    System.out.println("OUPUT OF KRUSKAL'S ALGORITHM:");
    // Write the code for Kruskal algorithm to find the minimum cost spanning tree here
    // and print the result in console with the following format:   
    /*==========================OUTPUT FORMAT===========================
            Minimun Cost of Spanning Tree = "....... "       

            Edges of the minimum cost spanning tree:
            ".........................................................."
    ================================================================== */
}

public static void  main(String[] args) {
    MakeGraph();
    Prim();
    Kruskal();  
}

}
```

Comment: So what is your specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation:

```
public class Library {
// Add the missing implementation to this class 

    java.util.ArrayList<Book> books;

    private static String openingHours = "The Library is open every day from 9AM to 5PM";
    private String a  ddress = "";
    private String[] collection = new String[10];
    private int collectionCount = 0;

    public Library(String libraries) {
        address = libraries;
        books = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    }

    public
            String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    void setaddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public static void printOpeningHours() {
        System.out.println("Library Hours: ");
        System.out.println(openingHours);
    }

    public void printAddress() {
        System.out.println(address);
    }

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        books.add(book);
    }

    public void printAvailableBooks() {
        boolean bookPresent = false;
        for (Book book : books) {
            if (!book.isBorrowed()) {
                System.out.println(book.getTitle());
                bookPresent = true;
            }
        }
        if (!bookPresent) {
            System.out.println("No such book in our catalog");
        }
    }

    private void borrowBook(String title) {
        int found = 0;
        for (Book book : books) {
            if (book.getTitle().equals(title)) {
                if (found == 0) {
                    found = 1;
                }
                if (!book.isBorrowed()) {
                    book.borrowed();
                    found = 2;
                    break;
                };
            }
        }
        if (found == 0) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, this book is not in our catalog.");
        } else if (found == 1) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, this book is already borrowed.");
        } else if (found == 2) {
            System.out.println("You successfully borrowed " + title);
        }
    }

    public void returnBook(String title) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (Book book : books) {
            if (book.getTitle().equals(title) && book.isBorrowed()) {
                book.returned();
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            System.out.println("You successfully returned " + title);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Library firstLibrary = new Library("Moylish Park, Limerick");
        Library secondLibrary = new Library("Clare Street, Limerick");
        Library thirdLibrary = new Library("Nenagh Road, Thurles");

        // Add four books to the first library
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("Java How To Program"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("What's new in Java 7?"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("Java in a nutshell"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("Pro Android 2"));

        // Print Opening hours and the addresses
        Library.printOpeningHours();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Library Addresses: ");
        firstLibrary.printAddress();
        secondLibrary.printAddress();
        thirdLibrary.printAddress();
        System.out.println();

        // Print the titles of all available books from both libraries
        System.out.println("Books available in the first library:");
        firstLibrary.printAvailableBooks();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Books available in the second library:");
        secondLibrary.printAvailableBooks();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Books available in the third library:");
        thirdLibrary.printAvailableBooks();
        System.out.println();

        // Return Java How To Program 
        System.out.println("Returning Java How To Program");
        firstLibrary.returnBook("Java How To Program");
        System.out.println();

        // Print the titles of available from the first library
        System.out.println("Books available in the first library:");
        firstLibrary.printAvailableBooks();
    }
}
```